# PHP File Upload Folder

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I want to upload file with php(text file) and always this file saved as names.txt(if the file exists from previous upload i want to be replaced with the new one) to the same directory the script is located. i found the below code online from a tutorial but i can't make it work .I get no file exists. I have posted the html file and the php file from upload to help me. thank you 
uploadfile.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="file_uploader.php" method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

file_uploader.php

```
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{
   copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "/uploads" ) or 
           die( "Could not copy file!");
}
else
{
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>
<li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];  ?> bytes
<li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];  ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`. If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

Your destination is invalid. You are passing a directory to destination file.

```
copy( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'] );
```

Comment: i tried to use move_uploaded_file() but i get the "No file specified!"

Comment: I also tried the code you gave me later and i get this "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/file_uploader.php on line 4"

Comment: You copied all of the line with ";" to in if statement ?

Comment: i saw that and i removed it . after that i i am still getting "No file specified"

Comment: i tried it on an other server and it worked...i had a problem with the  permissions....thank you

Answer (score 0):

for uploading file i use the code like as below

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  } 
  ?>
```